# Couchbase schema validation

Tags: couchbase, database-schema

I am new to Couchbase.

I know that couchbase is schemaless, as it is MongoDB.
I also saw that with MongoDB 3.6  there is a validationSchema, where we can tell an attribute it's data type.

I want to know if is it possible to in Couchbase 5, when creating a document insert the data type of that field, as in it is String, boolean, integer, etc...

Comment: @Stennie I think it makes sense to leave the MongoDb tag on here

Comment: @MatthewGroves The question is about Couchbase schema validation, so I didn't think it particularly on-topic for MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that Couchbase currently offers. It is a feature that has been requested, and is in the backlog (See [MB-28024](https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-28024), for instance).

One reason why Mongo can offer this is that while Couchbase uses pure JSON to store documents, MongoDB uses the "BSON" format. So, you can't export Mongo data to JSON directly, for instance. Instead you end up with "[Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)"

Comment: I think the second point on BSON is irrelevant: the JSON Schema draft describes pure JSON so MongoDB's validation also has to [extend JSON Schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#extensions) with awareness of BSON data types. There may be some other architectural reasons making validation more difficult to implement in Couchbase, but I suspect this is just a backlog feature request that hasn't been planned for a release yet.

Comment: So in Couchbase what does infer do? 
and the data types defined (https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datatypes.html)?   Aren't these usable?

Comment: `INFER` looks at a sample of the data to see what documents have in common with each other. I.e. if 40% of your documents have a field of type with a value of  "airline", it's going to find that commonality. The data types it returns are JSON data types that it finds. It does not enforce or validate data types, it tells you the shape of what's already there.

Comment: As for if they are "usable": you can do whatever you want with the results of INFER, but Couchbase does not use INFER or anything else to enforce/validate data types (yet)